# Is is possible to change an already setTimeout in different window width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, width, settimeout

I have a dropdown menu , which in dekstop version I would like to have delay of 1.5s , but when the width is already changed for tablet or iphone (for example less than 768px) I would like to change the settimeout to ZERO/0 ? Is it possible to be done at all ? Actually i am adding a class to the menu , so it could show up , but when it is closing i have set a settimeout of 1.55s. But it is a little bit annoying to wait so much if you are using a phone or tablet....

```
$menuHolder.on('click', function() {
  if ($menu.hasClass('open') || $navMenu.hasClass('visible')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $menu.removeClass('open');
    }, 1550);
    $navMenu.removeClass('visible')
    return;
  }
  $menu.addClass('open');
  $navMenu.addClass('visible');
})

var windowWidth = $win.width();
if (windowWidth < 769) {
  $menuHolder.on('click', function() {
    if ($menu.hasClass('open') || $navMenu.hasClass('visible')) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $menu.removeClass('open');
      }, 0);
      $navMenu.removeClass('visible')
      return;
    }
    $menu.addClass('open');
    $navMenu.addClass('visible');
  })
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to test the window width first, before you perform the `setTimeout`?

Comment: I have a couple of elements to be axact 12 with different time transition, so I tried to make some effects when the menu is opening and closing. But when the width is changed ,the effect is not so nice and there is no sense to wait so much time for closing the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the rest of your code works (we can't see where your variables like `$win`, `$menuHolder`, ... come from), I would approach your issue like this:

```
var windowWidth = $win.width();

$menuHolder.on('click', function() {
  if ($menu.hasClass('open') || $navMenu.hasClass('visible')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $menu.removeClass('open');
    }, (windowWidth < 769 ? 0 : 1550)); // here is the change for mobile devices
   $navMenu.removeClass('visible')
   return;
  }
  $menu.addClass('open');
  $navMenu.addClass('visible');
});
```

Hope that helps....

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working ... if i reverse 0:1550 and make it 1550 : 0 , it changes to zero for all widths .. so seems to be it is not doing anything i am using jquery as a library and because i am newbie i don`t know what is the purpose of this "?" --> question mark out there :)

Comment: Thats a short if statement, standard javascript, but same in many other languages like php or java.